# Github, push a new project in place of an old one

Tags: git, github, git-push

I have an iOS project setup to on github and over the past few days I have started to realize that I need to refactor most of my code. I build the project not abiding by many of the basics of MVC and now want to go back and fix everything.

The main issue is that the project is large enough where refactoring will be a massive pain. **Is there anyway that I can start a new project, build it to the place the current one is at (obviously with some major design changes) and push that up to github into the same branch instead of the original project?** If this is not clear please let me know.

Comment: Are you looking to keep the history of the old repository, and just (essentially) replace its current contents?

Comment: Yup basically like I did a major refactor but instead really just restarting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would expand on the given answers a bit, given your desire to keep your old history.  In this case, you don't want to start a new repo; you just want to "manhandle" the old one, clearing out old data and adding new.  You can accomplish this with the following steps:

1. cd into the root of your project dir.
2. Remove everything you don't want from the filesystem.  Be careful to **leave the .git/ folder**.  That's your repository's previous history.
3. Add whatever new stuff you want (new Xcode project, directory structure, etc.).
4. When you're ready to commit, `git status` is going to show you quite a mess (the size of which will depend upon how many files you used to have) of deletions and additions.  That's okay, this is where you take a broad brush to all of these entries, with `git add --all .`.  This will stage everything in your repo, deletions, new additions, all of it.
5. `git commit -m "My new beginning"`.
6. `git push origin myBranch --force`

Voila!  Your repository is completely made over, with the added bonus of retaining your previous history.

Comment: Thank you, I think that's everything I needed to know!

Answer (score 4):

You can. Just create your new project and type the following commands into a command line interface (cmd in Windows, terminal in linux).

```
cd /path/to/project
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/repo.git
git push origin master --force
```

That should do it.

Comment: So just to verify before I go through with this. This would keep all of my current git information (including commits) and just do a full push of the new project in place of the current master?

Comment: As a warning, this will wipe you history on the GitHub repo.

Comment: Sorry I missed this question earlier. Yes it will wipe the history on GitHub, however if you copy the old .git folder, as the accepted answer makes note, into this new folder, than you can keep your history.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new project on GitHub and in your .git/config , change the url to the new repo

```
[remote "origin"]
   fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
   url = git@github.com:[yourname]/[yournewrepo]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way is to copy your .git files/folders into the new project.

Answer (score 0):

Facing the similar problem I used suggestion of Stan (answer from Aug 31 '14 at 5:26).
Below details of an action I have taken with the positive result.

Assumptions:

- "old project" is on GitHub repo
- "new project" is created localy on your machine

Expectations:

- new project must be pushed to the old repo on github
- old commit history has to remain and be visible in github

Solution:

1) go to the "old project" folder on your local machine

2) find the hidden ".git" folder there and copy it

3) go to the new project folder on your machine

4) check if there is a .git folder (it is hidden so you need to show hidden files) - if there is a .git folder rename it, you can either delete it but its better to rename now and delete if all will go according to plan - if there is not .git folder go to the point 5 below. 5) paste previously copied .git folder (from old project) and paste it in the "new project" folder

Now the new project has a .git folder with all previous changes and history and includes the reference to the URL of you old repo on GitHub.

6) If you are using for example VS, you can check changes in code. There will be lots of them, or check them in terminal. You can check that old files have been deleted and new files added.

7)Push actual new project. This new project will be pushed to your old repo on GitHub. Check your git repo on web to be sure that all went well.

8) Now you can delete old project from your local machine and delete this renamed new git hidden folder (it was renamed in point 4).

Now you can develop your new project, keeping all old history with you.

Hope it helps.